# Configuring syslog for bash script logging

Tags: bash, scripts, syslog

I want to use syslog to do some bash script logging.

I see /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf, but I'm new to syslog. I want to configure local0 for logging for my scripts.

Should I be editing this configuration file? It has a bizarre name that throws me off. Or should I be creating some new file for my configuration that gets read somehow?

I just want to follow established standards here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the utility `logger`, as in the following example:

```
logger -p local0.notice -t MYTAG "my message"
```

In the default `rsyslog` configuration, it will appear on `/var/log/syslog` as

```
Jul 11 12:16:23 enzotib-laptop MYTAG: my message
```

If you want to log to some other file, you should modify `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, or better add another files under the same directory.